# Problems Updating File on GitHub Using Curl From Node JS

Tags: node.js, curl, github

I am trying to update a file on my GitHub repo using curl. Unfortunately it keeps giving me the same error message of "Problems parsing JSON". The command that I am using is:

```
curl -i -X PUT -H "Authorization: token <token>" -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d '{\"message\": \"<message>\", \"committer\": { \"name\": \"<name>\", \"email\": \"<email_address>\" }, \"content\": \"<contents_of_file_in_base64>\", \"sha\": \"<SHA_hash>\"}' https://api.github.com/repos/<user>/<repo>/contents/<data_path>
```

This command is being sent via node js. Anyone have any ideas what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Since you're using single quotes to wrap the json you don't need to escape the double quotes.

Comment: Ah thanks! I tried it without the escaped quotes and it still does not work.

Comment: try double quote
curl -i -X PUT -H "Authorization: token <token>" -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d "{\"message\": \"<message>\", \"committer\": { \"name\": \"<name>\", \"email\": \"<email_address>\" }, \"content\": \"<contents_of_file_in_base64>\", \"sha\": \"<SHA_hash>\"}" https://api.github.com/repos/<user>/<repo>/contents/<data_path>

Comment: Tried the double quotes around the JSON and still the same error.

Comment: put double quote for github url too

Comment: Tried putting double quotes around the GitHub URL and that gave same error message.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I solved it. I had to put 2 double quotes around all the property names and the values. As in {""valueName1"": ""value1"", ""valueName2"": ""value2""}.